# Discrete (Inverse) Haar (2D) transform implementations

Tags: image-processing, matlab, discrete-signals, wavelet

I am interested in implementations of the Haar transform, and its inverse, such that when composed always result in the identity operation.  My inputs are discrete ordinals within a given range - and I need the output of the Haar transform to be similarly discrete ordinal (or fixed-point) numbers.

I've worked on the basis that if my input signal consists uniformly distributed samples on the range $0..(2^n-1)$ and, so does my transformed signal, then in principle, my original signal should be reproduced perfectly by the inverse haar.

I've dabbled with this (Matlab) implementation using GNU Octave:

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/haar/haar.html

Which uses double precision values... forcing me to use round() to establish a discrete representation of the transformed data so as to fit the transformed representation into the same state-space as the original.  Unsurprisingly, I found I needed to use round() again to the output from the inverse transform.

It will probably come as no surprise that round(haar_2d_inverse(round(haar_2d(signal)))) is not quite the identity function for most values of signal... Anecdotally, there are typically a few out-by-one errors in the reconstructed signal - which seem roughly symmetric (+1 or -1 on a small number of the reconstructed samples) and this seems almost independent on the choice of n.

What I'd like to know is if there are 'better' implementations of haar_2d and haar_2d_inverse that work on ordinal samples?  Are the anomalies the consequence of the Haar implementation itself or the way I've applied round() at the intermediate stage?  If the latter, can I rectify this by scaling before rounding?

Comment: Seems like you'd need fixed-point math, rather than trying to approximate it w/ floating-point.

Comment: I suspect you're right - datageist - but that dependence on root-2 is relevant and might make this tricky.  I'm surprised that I can't find a sample implementation with a google search.

Answer (score 1):

I think in 2D Haar, $\sqrt{2}$ is not required, if the transform is applied simultaneously in both directions. It'd be of the form of $\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}$, which requires only fixed point implementation with the Q point being chosen based on number of levels. I had used this to implement Haar in C for embedded systems, and it works without rounding/truncation errors.

```
Note:
My rep's not 50, so posting as answer. If anyone can move it to the comments it'd be good.
```